# overwritten values while looping through lists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am converting some VBA code to Python.
I have an array and am looping through lists and adding values in location, however values are overwritten

The numpy array, nz, which has several hundred rows and columns has already been created. The code below works to a point. It places the correct values in the correct location except in the cases where the same location is used more than once. In these cases the new value overwrites the previous value.

```
for elem1, elem2 in zip(df['Header 1'], df['Header 2]'):
    a = (df.loc[df['Header 1'] == elem1, 'ID'].iloc[0]).astype(int)
    b = (df.loc[df['Header 2'] == elem2 , 'ID'].iloc[0]).astype(int)
    j = func1(a)
    k = func1(b)
    nz[a, j] = func2(a)
    nz[b, k] = func2(b)
    nz[a, k] = func2(b)
    nz[b, j] = func2(a)
```

How can I adapt this code so that if a new value is to be placed in the location of an existing value, e.g. the same values for (a, j) come up three times, it is added to the existing value? So, if the value of 1024 appears three times then in position (a, j) the array will have 3072.

To provide more detail.
The two lists that provide a and b contain strings which are node names, node1, node2, node 3 etc. each one in the respective list is checked against the 'ID' column and its respective position is returned, e.g. node 1 is 1, node 2 is 2 and so on. The nodes in the two lists are not arranged sequentially so it might be the case that the first pair is node1 and node 76, so therefore a becomes 1 and b becomes 76. There are about 1500 pairings. func1 returns integers and these values (a, b, j, k) then place the values that are returned from func2 into the array.
As an example (which is correct):

```
output:
nz.astype(int)[0]

array([      1,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,
             0,       0,       0,  262144,       0,       0,       0,
             0,       0,       0, 2097152,       0,       0,       0,
             0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,
             0,       0,       0,       0])
```

The values returned from the functions are correct, but the

```
nz[a, j] = func2(a)
```

always overwrites the previous value with the most current value so in cases where the pairing of (a,j) etc. comes up again I am not summing the values as I would like e.g. in the following case:

```
output:
nz.astype(int)[11]

array([ 2048,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
       65536,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     1,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0])
```

In this case [11,0] should be 6144 as that particular location occurs three times whilst going through the loop. The other values here are correct. I have compared this with the VBA code so I know that it is just this aspect in which I am falling down. The VBA line that places the value into the array is:

```
        nz(a, j) = nz(a, j) Or func(a)
```

I'm not sure how this might be reworked in Python.

Comment: You should give a look to [group_by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: Do you mean `nz[a, j] += func2(a)`  ?

Comment: I have tried nz[a, j] += func2(a) too but it does not return the correct values, if anything it causes more incorrect values to be returned.

Comment: Jérôme Richard do you have any suggestion as to how groupby might be used in this situation?

Comment: can you share the schema of `df` and `nz`. And also can you elaborate on what do you mean by `nz[a, j] += func2(a)` is returning incorrect values(I mean you aren't getting any error but incorrect values??). Passed input and expected output will be helpful as well in understanding the problem statement.